# Flutter WebView: Retrieve ALL fully generated html from a rendered URL(Similar to "Inspect Element")

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I am trying to get the titles of the events from [this webpage](https://www.volunteermatch.org/search/?l=Long%20Grove,%20IL%2060047,%20USA) and put them into a list:

[image]

[Since using HTTP did not get the fully generated html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63095735/flutter-dart-http-read-does-not-retrieve-full-html-from-given-url), I decided to try using `flutter_webview_plugin` to:

1. Load the desired URL on a hidden webview
2. Extract the fully generated HTML
3. Parse the HTML to get the titles I need

I am using this code to load the webview:

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(
    "https://www.volunteermatch.org/search/?l=Long%20Grove,%20IL%2060047,%20USA",
    hidden: true);
flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((viewState) async {
  if (viewState.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
    flutterWebviewPlugin
        .evalJavascript("document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        .then((html) {
      print(html);
      //some code to parse html
      flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is that even using JavaScript code to retrieve the HTML after the webview has finished loading **does not give me the same HTML that going to "Inspect Element" on Safari would give**, and none of the titles are in it either. What am I missing?

Comment: It's look like you are scraping the web page. please check below post https://itnext.io/write-your-first-web-scraper-in-dart-243c7bb4d05

Comment: @NileshSenta Thanks for the response, I'll look into the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I feel silly.

Since I was running the app on my iPhone, I was using Xcode to check the output of `print(html)`. For some reason, Xcode doesn't print out all of the `html` string:[image]

Xcode just leaves a `<...>`(bottom right corner circled in red) and decides not to print the rest.

Comment: any luck using this ?
i'm still getting the first html like http.get()
not the full html i see in webview

Comment: @Saifallak Basically my issue was just an Xcode print issue, and the code I used actually did get all of the html.